# aplicar css al hacer click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

veran lo que yo intento emular es como muestra el siguiente ejemplo del enlace

https://i.imgur.com/45vWpaC.mp4

intente hacerlo asi pero igual el css aplica a los dos al mismo tiempo , lo que yo busco es que el css se aplique en 1 de los dos div  si se aplica en el primero entonces se borra en el segundo y asi viceversa.

```js
 $('.toggle-click').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0);
        $(this).css('border', '5px solid red')
      }
    else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1);
      $(this).css('border', 'none')
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-click" style="margin: 10px auto; width: 200px; padding: 30px 0; cursor: pointer; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">Elemento  1</div>

<div class="toggle-click" style="margin: 10px auto; width: 200px; padding: 30px 0; cursor: pointer; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">Elemento 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es agregarle `style`, creo que podrias limpiar sus estilos y luego adicionar el borde, con eso estaría resuelto.

```js
$('.toggle-click').on('click',function(){
     $('.toggle-click').removeClass('show-red');
     $(this).addClass('show-red');
  });
```

```css
.show-red {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="toggle-click" style="margin: 10px auto; width: 200px; padding: 30px 0; cursor: pointer; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">Elemento 1</div>

<div class="toggle-click" style="margin: 10px auto; width: 200px; padding: 30px 0; cursor: pointer; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">Elemento 2</div>
```